# Migrate to new eclipse version on Mac gives No class found error

Tags: java, macos

I upgraded to the newest Mac Pro running Big Sur (11.4) from my 12 year old Mac Pro running Mojave (10.14.6). The old version of Eclipse was version was Kepler service release 2. When I installed the Mac and restored from backup, Eclipse flat out would not run, so I deleted it and downloaded and installed the latest version 2021-03 (4.19.0). I also updated JAVA SE to version 16.0.1 from Java version SE 7.

When I tried to run/compile a previous working project, I get:
[image]

I then decided to update the libraries found in the Java Build Path properties to the latest I could find:
[image]

to see if that made any difference. It didn't. I'm probably missing something very basic but I don't know what, since I use Eclipse only rarely.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to go down the rabbit hole and download the missing jars in the error log, one after another. It just kept getting deeper and deeper with no end in sight. Just didn't quite pass the smell test.

Hmmm. I originally downloaded eclipse from the main elcipse.org page and went to the downloads button and installed it. Turns out the eclipse directory was only 21.2 MB. Plugin directory was basically empty. Hmmm.

I stumbled on the download file  eclipse-SDK-4.19-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.dmg after looking for a SWT download. This file was the eclipse version that was 295.4MB in size. Double hmmm. So I ran it. Needless to say I was startled when my project compiled and ran right off the bat. Gee, thanks eclipse. Can you make it any more difficult for your Mac users? Anyway after a wasted day of head banging... problem solved.